# What happens at UK border with pre-settled/settled status as a non-EEA citizen with an expired BRC?

Tags: uk, uk-residents, hong-kong-citizens

Hong Kong national A has pre-settled status in the UK. Hong Kong national B has settled status in the UK. They travel to Hong Kong on 1 Feb 2024, their BRC will expire on 10 Feb 2024, and they return to the UK on 20 Feb 2024.

[The carrier can, at their discretion, allow them to board the plane to the UK](https://the3million.org.uk/faq/brc-expired-lost). The carrier has informally confirmed they will allow this.

If they do fly back to the UK with the expired card, what happens for A and B at the border in the UK?
[Anecdotal evidence](https://www.reddit.com/r/ukvisa/comments/owz21j/noneu_with_settled_status_euss_but_with_an/) suggests that they will be admitted to the UK after proving their settled status to the immigration officer.

Is there a way for A and B to obtain non-expired travel documents? Replacing an expired BRP typically takes eight weeks, which puts A and B past their departure date on 10 Feb (today is 25 Dec 2023). Also, [it seems they can only apply for the replacement card once the original expired](https://www.gov.uk/uk-residence-card/replace). For people whose BRC expired abroad, there exists [the EU Settlement Scheme travel permit](https://www.gov.uk/euss-travel-permit). However, getting a decision typically takes 3 weeks, which is longer than the 20 day stay they will have in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 4):

> The carrier can, at their discretion, allow them to board the plane to the UK. The carrier has informally confirmed they will allow this.

This is not that relevant as HK SAR Passports holders are allowed [6 months visa-free in the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Chinese_citizens_of_Hong_Kong)

> If they do fly back to the UK with the expired card, what happens for A and B at the border in the UK?

They will likely be admitted back, as [they don't even need the BRC to be renewed](https://www.gov.uk/uk-residence-card/replace) before travel :

> You need to replace your UK residence card if you plan to travel abroad and return to the UK and **all** of the following apply:

> - you would usually need a visa to travel to the UK but you have pre-settled or settled status under the EU Settlement Scheme
> - you’ve reported your UK residence card as lost or stolen, or it’s expired
> - you’re in the UK when you apply for a replacement residence card

This first point doesn't apply, so they can likely rest assured

Comment: Thanks! You can consider to extend your post by adding extra detail. “This is not that relevant as HK SAR Passports holders are allowed 6 months visa-free in the UK” This visa-free entry is only for some visa-free activities, such as tourism, business, and visiting friends and family. Work and live in the UK is not a visa-free activity, so this rule does not apply to A and B. Carriers usually ask HK SAR passport holders for the purpose of travel, and if A and B tell the truth, then the carrier may deny boarding.

Comment: You quoted a paragraph stating A and B need not renew their BRC. However, the next paragraph from the page you quote states: “If you’re outside the UK when your card needs replacing, you need to apply for an EU Settlement Scheme travel permit to return to the UK. You can apply for a replacement residence card when you’re in the UK.” I don’t fully understand this, and it seems to suggest to me that A and B need to apply for an extra travel document when they’re in Hong Kong. It would be nice if your post covered this paragraph as well.

Comment: And you mention the Registered Traveller Service. What you say is correct, but HK SAR passport holders that want to enter the UK to live and work and have the right to be in the UK due to the EUSS cannot register for this service.

Comment: 2. The wording makes me highly think that if you don't need to replace it in the UK, you don't abroad

Comment: 1. First statement was a direct mention of the BRC replacement page

Comment: @user505117 Indeed, removing that part

Comment: Thanks, very helpful and I appreciate the effort